# cannot urllib.urlencode a URL in python

Tags: python, urlencode, urllib

Why am I getting this error when trying to urlencode this string

```
 >>> callback = "http://localhost/application/authtwitter?twitterCallback"
 >>> urllib.urlencode(callback)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1261, in urlencode
      raise TypeError
 TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That's not what that function does:

```
urlencode(query, doseq=0)
    Encode a sequence of two-element tuples or dictionary into a URL query string.
```

Are you looking for?

- `urllib.quote(callback)` Python 2
- `urllib.parse.quote(callback)`  Python 3

Comment: This answer only works for Python 2.  For Python 3, it is urllib.parse.quote.  Can you add an addendum?

Answer (score 19):

Python is not PHP. You want [`urllib.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) instead.

Comment: It was helpful to me.  It made me look closer.  Since I am coming from php.

Answer (score 13):

**urlencode()**
    This function encode two-element tuples or dictionary only.

```
  >>> import urllib  
  >>> dict = { 'First_Name' : 'Jack', 'Second_Name' : "West"}
  >>> urllib.urlencode(dict)
  'First_Name=Jack&Second_Name=West
```

**quote_plus()**
     This function encode url string

```
  >>> import urllib   
  >>> url ="https://www.google.com/"
  >>> urllib.quote_plus(url)
  'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F'
```

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3

In Python 3, the quote and urlencode functionalities are located in the module [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Some Examples:

### (un)quote

#### urllib.parse.**[quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)**

> Replace special characters in string using the %xx escape.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote('https://www.google.com/')
'https%3A//www.google.com/'
```

Similarly, to reverse this operation, use urllib.parse.unquote:

#### urllib.parse.**[unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)**

> Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('https%3A//www.google.com/')
'https://www.google.com/'
```

### (un)quote_plus

#### urllib.parse.**[quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus)**

> Like quote(), but also replace spaces by plus signs, as required for quoting HTML form values when building up a query string to go into a URL.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus('https://www.google.com/')
'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F'
```

Similarly, to reverse this operation, use urllib.parse.unquote_plus:

#### urllib.parse.**[unquote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus)**

> Like unquote(), but also replace plus signs by spaces, as required for unquoting HTML form values.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote_plus('https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F')
'https://www.google.com/'
```

### urlencode

#### urllib.parse.**[urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)**

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> d = {'url': 'https://google.com', 'event': 'someEvent'}
>>> urrlib.parse.urlencode(d)
'url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&event=someEvent'
```