# Trying to grab a section of a URL and then amend it to the end of a line in python

Tags: python

So I am trying to a session ID from the end of a URL, and then add to another URL. I am basically opening an internal site which goes to a homepage, and then to search for an item, goes to another page. To get around having to give out the password we use a script for it, which we currently use autohotkey, which doesn't work very well, has a lot of issues, and generally is more of a pain than just loading the site and logging in.

So here is my progress:

First I tried:

```
sid = urlparse(browser.current_url).query
url= 
urljoin('http://internal.site/BelManage/find_pc_by_name.asp?', 
sid)
```

That failed, which makes sense. So then I imported urlencode and did:

```
updateurl='http://internal.site/BelManage/find_pc_by_name.asp?{}'.format(urllib.parse.urlencode(sid))
```

This fails stating not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object.

Because I have to grab the sid with .query from urlparse it means I cannot use a string concatenation, unless I convert sid as a set to a string, which I am not for sure of an easy way to do that.

Any ideas of a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib.urlencode: TypeError not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947568/urllib-urlencode-typeerror-not-a-valid-non-string-sequence-or-mapping-object)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot everything, and then remembered, and was able to get this working.
I converted sid to a str via str(sid), defined the url variable with the address and a simple concatenation and it seems to be working now.